# How to use "BETWEEN" in aws-sdk-go Dynamodb QueryInput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am using aws-sdk-go for dynamodb. I need to collect some items from my DB. The filtering conditions are **deviceid: xyz, time >= 10** and **time <= 20.**

**time** is the sort key for my db and **deviceid** is the primary key. I understand I have to use **BETWEEN** for achieving  my goal. My Implementations are not successful and as follows:

```
var queryInput = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName: aws.String(dbName),
    KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
        "deviceid": {
            ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
            AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                {
                    S: aws.String("xyz"),
                },
            },
        },
        "time": {
            ComparisonOperator: aws.String("BETWEEN"),
            AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                {
                    N: aws.String("10"),
                    N: aws.String("20"),
                },
            },

        },
    },
}
```

What are the mistakes I made here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `time` value should be given as mentioned below:-

```
"time": {
            ComparisonOperator: aws.String("BETWEEN"),
            AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                {
                    N: aws.String("10"),                        
                },
                {
                    N: aws.String("20"),                        
                },
            },
        },
```